# Flutter WebView()

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How to iterate a list of **multiple** URLs (which are strings) in the "initialUrl" parameter in the WebView()? So that when I click the 1st button I am directed to the 1st url and 2nd for the 2nd url and so on.

Comment: you can make custom widget for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**
I am giving a solution as per your provided [github link](https://github.com/theyashjha/lib),

1. In home.dart uncomment below code and pass `yashjha[index]`.

```
     Navigator.push(
                 context,
                 MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => WebPage(yashjha[index])),
               );
```

2. In webpage.dart get the variable to so something like this,

```
class WebPage extends StatefulWidget {
  String yashjha;

  WebPage(this.yashjha);

  @override
  _WebPageState createState() => _WebPageState();
}

class _WebPageState extends State<WebPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: WebView(
        initialUrl: widget.yashjha,
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Find complete solution of your project in [this repository](https://github.com/raviganwal/flutter_webview_url_list)**

---

**Original Answer**

Take a StatefulWidget Declare a `WebViewController` like this,

`WebViewController controller;`

create list of urls,

```
List<String> urlList=['https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/editor','https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/test-drive'];
String url;
```

then on each button press change URL,

```
          RaisedButton(onPressed: () {
              url= urlList[0];
              setState(() {
                print(url);
                controller.loadUrl(url);
              });
            }),
            RaisedButton(onPressed: () {
              url = urlList[1];
              setState(() {
                print(url);
                controller.loadUrl(url);
              });
            }),
```

Now inside webview declare your controller,

```
            Expanded(
              child: WebView(
                initialUrl: url,
                onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
                  controller = webViewController;
                },
              ),
            ),
```

I have created a [working example here](https://gist.github.com/raviganwal/aaec22f6ef4ab5b2ef7f7af3bba5f201)

---

Comment: this is not working correctly. this is just loading the site without a scaffold and its overflowing. after so many trials and errors i've concluded that a loop to iterate the items will work here. so that when "when(if) i click 1st button, it loads 1st url, 2nd button fot 2nd url". so if you can help here?

Comment: If you want a scaffold then wrap your code in a scaffold. I just gave you an idea [HERE](https://gist.github.com/raviganwal/aaec22f6ef4ab5b2ef7f7af3bba5f201). Also please post what code you're trying in your question.

Comment: Okay I found your problem and fixed it!

Comment: See my updated answer and find your complete solution here https://github.com/raviganwal/flutter_webview_url_list

Comment: wow. this is unbelievable thank you so much for helping me. this is amazing and its working!!! i'll go mad i think. thank you once again. 

Comment: but i didnt get the idea of using the constructor here. can you please explain it?

Comment: Because you want to pass a url on each tap event to  ` WebPage(yashjha[index])` whats why you need to create a constructor to fetch it. Also, mark this answer as accepted to other people facing this issue might find this answer helpful.

Comment: alright. now i get it. and yeah marked this answer correct! thanks again.